# Can the Android Snapdragon Vulnerabilities be used to root a phone permanently?

Tags: android, vulnerability, kernel

Would it be possible to use the discovered vulnerabilities (CVE-2016-0819 and CVE-2016-0805) to root a phone permanently without any dataloss and install applications like SuperSU?

Answer (score 1):

There will propably establish a praxis like:
`Downgrade to vulnerable Software` -> `Execute Exploit / Run Code as root` -> `Install / Upgrade Software to save level`

There is a [post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z5/general/root-using-vulnerabilities-snapdragon-t3338173) in the xda-developers board adressing this technique.